# How to safely resume cache operation on client side after Hazelcast restart?

Tags: caching, spring-boot, hazelcast

Whenever I restart hazelcast server, without restarting client in spring boot. I'm getting following error :

```
    03-01-2018 16:44:17.966 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] ERROR  o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet].log - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClientNotActiveException: Partition does not have owner. partitionId : 203] with root cause
java.io.IOException: Partition does not have owner. partitionId : 203
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientSmartInvocationServiceImpl.invokeOnPartitionOwner(ClientSmartInvocationServiceImpl.java:43)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocation.invokeOnSelection(ClientInvocation.java:142)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:122)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientProxy.invokeOnPartition(ClientProxy.java:152)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:147)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.getInternal(ClientMapProxy.java:245)
    at com.hazelcast.client.proxy.ClientMapProxy.get(ClientMapProxy.java:240)
    at com.hazelcast.spring.cache.HazelcastCache.lookup(HazelcastCache.java:139)
    at com.hazelcast.spring.cache.HazelcastCache.get(HazelcastCache.java:57)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doGet(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:71)
```

If I enabled hot-restart, the issue is solved. But is there a way to resume client application without restarting it and hot-restart is disabled ?

Answer (score 1):

Hazelcast client tries to reconnect to the cluster if the connection drops. It uses `ClientNetworkConfig.connectionAttemptLimit` and `ClientNetworkConfig.connectionAttemptPeriod` elements to configure how frequently it will try. `connectionAttemptLimit` defines the number of attempts on a disconnection and `connectionAttemptPeriod` defines the period between two retries in ms. Please see the usage example below:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().setConnectionAttemptLimit(5);
clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().setConnectionAttemptPeriod(5000);
```

Starting with Hazelcast 3.9, you can use `reconnect-mode` property to configure how the client will reconnect to the cluster after it disconnects. It has three options:

- The option `OFF` disables the reconnection.
- `ON` enables reconnection in a blocking manner where all the waiting invocations will be blocked until a cluster connection is established or failed.
- The option `ASYNC` enables reconnection in a non-blocking manner where all the waiting invocations will receive a `HazelcastClientOfflineException`.

Its default value is `ON`. You can see a configuration example below:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.getConnectionStrategyConfig()
        .setReconnectMode(ClientConnectionStrategyConfig.ReconnectMode.ON);
```

By using these configuration elements, you can resume your client without restarting it.

Comment: Actually I have enabled reconnect mode, the error occurs only after number of attempts exceeded. So the configuration above doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: It looks like the migration took longer than the client reconnection. Can you please share the `connectionAttemptLimit ` and `connectionAttemptPeriod ` values of yours? Have you tried to increase them?

Comment: Increasing those fields will reduce likelihood of the error, but it's not solving the actual issue. For my case, I need the application to be resilient, able to recover after hazelcast server crash/restarted for indefinite of time

Comment: You can set `connectionAttemptLimit ` to `0` (zero) in order to make client try forever. But if you still face `Partition does not have owner` after the client connects to cluster, there may be some other issues to look for.